# How many beaches are suitable for swimming in Cebu City?

Tags: beaches, philippines, swimming

As I research it, there might only be beaches used for commercial/cargo purposes. I can't find beaches for swimming. But when I search google images for Cebu City, a bunch of beautiful beaches come up. When I looked in tripadvisor, it came up with [a resort and a park](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g298460-Activities-c57-t52-Cebu_City_Cebu_Island_Visayas.html), so are those the only ones?

I am interested in publicly accessible beaches. In my understanding of resort beaches, they would be excluded from this count because the resort doesn't let the public in to the beach. But maybe resorts in Cebu are different.

Comment: Welcome! Subjective questions tend to get closed pretty often, as per the [help], so it might be worth rephrasing to say, most popular statistically or something so that it can be answered objectively.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the keen eye @MarkMayo. I'll try to make this objective.

Comment: That was a helpful link @pnuts, thanks. And what can I clarify about my Q? What is hard to understand?

Comment: @pnuts, other way around. I would prefer in, but would settle for nearby.

Comment: `fun` is subjective, `nice` is subjective - it doesn't matter who thinks it is fun or nice; because these two are not things you can objectively measure. Even by locals as each may have their own preference.  People with children might have different criterion for "nice" and "fun"; singles may have other criteria, surfers may have others, sunbathers others, etc. It is like asking "what is the best, clean and fun mall in Los Angeles".  The only thing answerable here _definitely_ is which beach is the closest to the city without being "in" or vice versa.

Comment: Ok. How do I delete this? Sorry for the bad question.

Comment: @ColeTrumbo Don't delete. Edit. The community will reopen once it is on topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't swimming, not in Cebu City itself. The Cebu City waterfront is on reclaimed land that forms Cebu International Port along the Mactan Channel, the narrow strait between Cebu and Mactan islands. It is the largest domestic port in the Philippines and, as is typical, is lined with ferry ports and passenger terminals, docks, piers, shipping yards, tankers, storage, etc.

It is outside of Cebu City proper that you find the gorgeous natural beaches of which this nation of more than 7,000 islands is so justifiably proud.

For proximity, nearest is Mactan Island, connected to mainland Cebu by two bridges (Mandaue-Mactan Bridge and Marcelo Fernan Bridge), and just a few kilometers from the city proper.  There, you'll find several public beaches, both in Lapu-Lapu: Maribago (Pajac-Maribago Road) and Vano (Marigondon Beach Road).

As for [public beaches on Cebu](http://sugbo.ph/2016/8-beautiful-public-beaches-in-cebu/), the web site of the island, Sugbo.ph, shares these (and a wealth of other resources):

- Logon Beach in Malapascua, 80 km going north of Cebu City, reachable by bus bound for Maya in the North Bus Terminal, and a boat ride in Maya Port to Malapascua.
- Lambug Beach in Badian 100 km southwest of Cebu City. Take a bus bound for Badian in South Bus Terminal. Ask the conductor to drop you off in Lambug, Beach. Then you will need to ride a tricycle or habal-habal to reach to the beach.
- Tingko Beach in Alcoy, perhaps the most popular in all of Cebu, it's 100 km south of Cebu City. At the South Bus Terminal, take a bus going to Oslob, ask the conductor to drop you off right at the beach.
- Basdaku Beach in Moalboal, 100 km southwest of Cebu City. South Bus Terminal, bus to Moalboal, ask to be dropped off in Basdaku. and then ride a tricycle or habal-habal to the  beach.
- Hidden Beach in Aloguinsan (literally hidden), southwest 60 km from Cebu City, take a v-hire or van bound for Pinamungajan in Citilink Terminal, ask to be dropped off at Hidden Beach, then ride a habal-habal.
- Matutinao Beach in Badian, southwest 100 km from Cebu City, take the bus to Badian in the South Bus Terminal, ask for drop off in Lambug, then ride a tricycle or habal-habal to the beach.
- Santiago White Beach in Camotes, 90 km north of Cebu City, in the North Bus Terminal, take a bus bound for Danao City, then ride a boat that goes to San Francisco in Camotes.
- Santa Fe Beach in Bantayan, 150 km going north from Cebu City, take a bus bound for Hagnaya from the North Bus Terminal, then the ferry to Santa Fe.

Answer (score 0):

The beaches within Cebu City aren't good for public swimming since they're being too industrialized (lots of ports in the area). The best beaches are mostly found in South Cebu. I recommend going to Lambug Beach (Badian) or Basdaku in Moalboal. This is about 2 hours away from Cebu City.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I deleted the link to your site because I don't think it was really relevant to the question and we don't like our site being used to promote other sites. Please see our [guidelines on promotion](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) for more information.